# PysPark job executes in PySpark shell but throws exception when using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am have written a job that queries a table. When I run the query in the PySpark shell there are no errors. However, when I run the query in a script through `spark-submit` I get the following exception:

```
parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file s3://xxx/xxx/part-xxxx-xxxx.snappy.parquet
```

Even using a script as simple as

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("yarn")
    .appName("Test")
    .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
    .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", 9000)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM xxx.xxx LIMIT 100")
df.show()
```

throws the same exception. It seems to only happen with this particular table which would lead me to believe that the data is corrupt, however this would mean the same error would show in the PySpark shell.

Comment: Could be a schema issue or the Decimal type issue as mentioned here : https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1027/im-getting-a-parquetioparquetdecodingexception-can.html

Comment: @user238607 but I wonder why it works find the shell still? I will try adding a manually defined schema to see if it changes anything